# Improve performance of NOT IN Clause query

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a query to fetch data from 2 tables which is written using the **NOT IN CLAUSE**.
Now the data in these tables has increased and the query is now taking more time to execute. I read few solutions on stack overflow and found that we can increase the performance by either **using left join or not exits**

The IN clause query gives around 500 rows but after using Left join or Not exits i get around 811 rows.

Existing query with IN Clause

```
select t1.lm_id from table1 t1,table2 t2 where
          t1.lm_id like 'B-%'  
           and t1.dt > '20201231'
           and t2.int_val = 1 and 
           t1.lm_id = t2.lm_id  
        and t1.lm_id not in (
                 SELECT t2.lm_id FROM t2 t2 WHERE t2.dt = '20201231'
                 and t2.lm_id like 'B-%' and t2.int_val = 1
        )
```

I changed the above given query using **NOT EXITS and LEFT JOIN**

NOT EXITS Query

```
select  t1.lm_id from table1 t1 where
            t1.lm_id like 'B-%'  
            and t1.dt_valid_to > '20201231'
            and not exists (
                SELECT t2.lm_id FROM table2 t2 WHERE
                t1.lm_id = t2.lm_id
                and t2.dt = '20201231'
                and t2.lm_id like 'B-%' and t2.int_val = 1
        )
```

LEFT JOIN Query

```
select  t1.lm_id  from table1 as t1 
        left  join table2 as t2 
        on  t2.lm_id =t1.lm_id
        and t2.dt = '20201231'
        and t1.dt_valid_to > '20201231'
        and t2.lm_id like 'B-%' and t2.int_val = 1
        where 
            t1.lm_id like 'B-%'
            and t1.dt_valid_to > '20201231'
            and t2.lm_id is null
            and t2.int_val = 1
```

Can some one help me in fixing this. I am unable to understand what mistake I am doing.

Comment: should probably [edit] to include table schemas, sample input data, desired output data, and an example of current wrong output with each query.

Comment: as Gordon has pointed out (in his answer+comments) these queries are not the 'same', so the first thing you need to do is determine which query returns the correct results (I'm guessing the first/currently-in-use query); next, why do you think you have a performance issue? I'm not saying you can't have a performance issue, but it would help if you could quantify this performance issue? does the query plan show an unexpected table scan, or perhaps an expensive sort-merge operation? does the query take a 'long time' to run and if so please defined 'long time'

Comment: it might also help if you updated the question with a more specific tag, as well as textual description, describing which Sybase RDBMS product you're using (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not the same, because the `NOT IN` has a `CROSS JOIN` between `table1` and `table2`:

```
from table1 t1, table2 t
```

The `WHERE` conditions are not the same.  And although I would expect this to *increase* the number of rows, it could also decrease the number as well.

Use the query that does what you want -- which is presumably one of the last two.  If you want to join the tables, use `JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`,  not a comma.

Comment: So what should I do to improve the performance of the NOT IN clause query?

Comment: @AtulRai . . . You are comparing apples and oranges.  The queries do different things.

Comment: Ok thanks , atleast I now know that I am taking wrong path

Comment: @AtulRai . . . You might want to ask a *new* question, providing sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Sure I will do that